# После обновление до Java 8 крашится приложение

Tags: android, gradle

После обновления до java 8 приложение перестало собираться. `build.gradle` выполняется прекрасно. Когда я пытаюсь запустить приложение на эмуляторе, то вываливается следующий стактрейс:

IDE: Android Studio

> Process: com.blackmamba.gopgame, PID: 1873
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.blackmamba.gopgame/com.blackmamba.gopgame.MainMenu}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.blackmamba.gopgame.MainMenu" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.blackmamba.gopgame-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.blackmamba.gopgame.MainMenu" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.blackmamba.gopgame-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
>               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>       Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blackmamba.gopgame.MainMenu
>               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>               ... 13 more
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
 }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   mavenLocal()
}
android {

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.blackmamba.gopgame"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
 }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
 }
}

dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.1.1'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.blackmamba.gopgame"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <activity
        android:name="MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="HeroSelector"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Что подразумевается под "обновления до java 8"? Вы установили в систему JDK 8 или в приложении указали чтобы оно собиралось под java 8?

Comment: Если у вас Linux убедитесь что у вас используется именно та версия Java что вы установили, см `update-alternatives`

Answer (score 3):

Изначально компилятор Java Android поддерживал только версию Java 6, однако в Android SDK Tools 22.6 (март 2014) была добавлена поддержка Java 7 с некоторыми ограничениями:

> Added support for Java 7 language features like multi-catch, try-with-resources, and the diamond operator. These features require version 19 or higher of the Build Tools. Try-with-resources requires minSdkVersion 19; the rest of the new language features require minSdkVersion 8 or higher.

то есть `Try-with-resources` доступен только с Android 4.4, а Build Tools должен быть версии не ниже 19 . Java 8 на данный момент не поддерживается вовсе.

Если на компьютере установлена более новая версия Java, необходимо указать ограничение версии для сборки проекта и ,естественно, не использовать никаких операторов, классов и конструкций более новых версий Java.

Однако в `build.gradle` лучше все же указать версию сборки Java 6:

```
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}
```

Кроме того, необходимо убедиться, что версия JDK используемая в проекте соответствует актуальной версии на компьютере: `File -> Project Structure -> SDK location (слева) -> JDK location`

Так же, при столь глобальных изменениях, как смена компилятора, не помешает сделать `Build -> Claean Project` и `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Фактически установленная на компьютер версия Java должна быть не менее Java 6 или более новая. Так, у меня установлена Java 8 и все прекрасно работает при учете того, что написано выше.

Answer (score 0):

Для разработки под Android Java 8 не подходит.

[Согласно требованиям](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) - требуется Java 6, хотя экспериментально установлено, что Java 7 подходит для Android >= 5.0

Попробуйте установить флаги компилятора чтобы он генерил код совместимый с Java 6 (не уверен что поможет)

Comment: на java 7 все до этого работало вполне себе отлично.

Comment: А у меня в Eclipse, вроде 8 ява (в switch строки успешно пихаю) и всё работает...

Comment: Пробовал изменить флаги компилятора до java 6, а потом java 7. К сожалению, не помогло. Так же попробовал импортировать проект на gradle с нуля, но проблема не изменилась.

Comment: Java 7 не только подходит для Android >= 5.0 но и требуется - `JDK 7 is required when developing for Android 5.0 and higher.` http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio

Comment: @VladimirSokolov судя по логам у вас Linux и есть проблема с подключением либ x64 - может попробуете установить 32-х разрядную JDK?

Answer (score 0):

Обновите Android Studio и все tools в SDK до последней версии.

Создайте новый проект и запустите. Если это сработает это скопируйте исходники из этого проекта в новый. Некоторым это помогает.

Также в манифесте поставьте точку перед **всеми** Activity:

Т.е. вместо

```
 <activity
        android:name="MainMenu">
        ...
 </activity>
```

вот так:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu">
        ...
 </activity>
```

См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20924305/1159507

UPD. У меня с декабря 2014 года используется JDK 8 x64 как основная и единственная и все работает без проблем в Intellij Idea, Eclipse и Android Studio на 64 разрядном Linux.

Comment: и ты в это веришь? :)

Comment: @Barmaley ответ отмечен как верный и у него 15 плюсов, если попробовать хуже не будет ? :)

Comment: Напоминает анекдот: едут в машине программист с пассажирами и водитель. Машина глохнет, ни туда ни сюда. Водитель ковыряется ковыряется, пассажиры тоже помогают чем могут - свечи, карбюратор, бензин -  ничего не помогает. В общем все кирдык. Сидят в машине и курят. Программист говорит: а давайте все выйдем из машины, закроем его на ключ и войдем заново!